# HTML, Javascript: How do I load an HTML element when the user scrolls it into view?

Tags: html, dom, scroll

Such as, in my case, an element at the bottom of each page with a Disqus comment thread inside.  These alone take a few seconds to load on each page, and it would greatly improve performance if they could be loaded only if the user actually views them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to suggest handling the scroll event and then checking if the element in question has moved into the viewport, but while researching I found this:

[jquery-appear](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/) - jQuery plugin to call a function when an element becomes visible

(via another question here on SO: [jQuery - Check if element is visible after scroling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling))